# "Authentication credentials were not provided." Thunder client Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

> I am trying to restrict dashboard access only, which can be viewed
> only when the token is passed into the header but...

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.POST['user_name']
        name = request.POST['first_name']
        lastname = request.POST['last_name']
        designation = request.POST['designation']
        password = request.POST['password']
        email = request.POST['email']
        user = MyUser(username=user_name, first_name=name,
                      last_name=lastname)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        obj = Employee(user=user, first_name=name,
                       last_name=lastname, designation=designation, email=email, isactive=False)
        obj.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        # mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
        # message = render_to_string('Auth/email_template.html', {
        #     'user': user,
        #     'domain': current_site.domain,
        #     'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)),
        #     'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        # })
        # to_email = email
        # send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [to_email])
        obj, create = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return JsonResponse(obj.key, safe=False)
```

**login view**

```
 @csrf_exempt
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def login_in(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.data['first_name']
            password = request.data['password']
    
            user = authenticate(username=name, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                tok = Token.objects.get(user=request.user)
                return JsonResponse(tok.key, safe=False)
            else:
                print('Not authenticated')
        return render(request, 'Auth/user.html')
```

**Dashboard view**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def dash_board(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        return render(request, 'Auth/dashboard.html', {
            'user': request.user,

        })
```

**Response I am getting from thunder client**

```
{
  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

> I am passing request headers using thunder client in which
> Authorization header is set to

```
Token d2ed0c39f31bb1c080753bkldd0f4c0ab96b5a07
```

Comment: Same issue with me.. Did you find the solution?

Comment: yes just check the extra space that you're giving between `token (key)`

Comment: I think the issue is that thunder client sent token by default with 'Bearer' keyword, while drf accept tokens with 'Token' keyword.

Comment: in my case i had left extra in between and yes off course, you have to mention `Token` not `bearer`

Answer (score 2):

Thunder client sends the token with the `Bearer` prefix. But drf accepts token prefix as `Token`. You need to change the Token prefix to `Token`.

[image: see where to change in the screenshot]